# How to use notify-send in service systemcd

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a service and this service execute some shell script

i want to run this script every 15min ***(it's 1min for now)***

### suspending.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello world'
notify-send 'Please take a rest and come back again' &
sleep 10
systemctl suspend
```

### suspend.service

```sh
[Unit]
Description=suspend service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/<user>/suspending.sh
User=<user>
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### suspend.timer

```sh
[Unit]
Description=Suspend the system

[Timer]
Unit=suspend.service
OnUnitActiveSec=1min


[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

> sudo journalctl -f -u suspend.service

```sh
systemd[1]: Started suspend service.
suspending.sh[7578]: Hello world
suspending.sh[7585]: Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
suspending.sh[7585]: Failed to suspend system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
suspending.sh[7585]: Failed to start suspend.target: Interactive authentication required.
suspending.sh[7585]: See system logs and 'systemctl status suspend.target' for details.
systemd[1]: suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

this will echo the `Hello World` but does'nt show any notification..

what is wrong?

Comment: install `xhost` and  `xhost +`.

Answer (score 0):

You need special access to send notification :

```
suspending.sh[7585]: Failed to start suspend.target: Interactive authentication required.
```

The lazy solution would be to replace `<user>` by root. The Safe option would be to create a specific user with the correct permissions to send notification.

```sh
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/<user>/suspending.sh # Should not be in the home folder
User=<user>  # Should be a special user with permission
```